# using continue in a for loop to skip an array value

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have tried to retrieve data from a database and then compare it with a variable  and using for loop and continue to skip numbers found in the database but it only  skips the first number from loop this what i want to do with the data

- To count the number of loops (how many vouchers not posted)
- To also know the vouchers that are not posted in the dbase
  so as to input new voucher numbers in database after all the last ones are all used
  This is my code:

  ```
  $hostname = "localhost";
  $user = "****";
  $pass = "*******";
  $database = "test";
  $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
  $from = 1001;
  $to = 2000;
  $query="SELECT * FROM voucher_posted WHERE voucher BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ORDER BY  voucher ASC";
  $squery=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
  while($array=mysql_fetch_array($squery)){$voucher[]=$array['voucher'];}
  for($from;$from<=$to;$from++)
  {
  foreach($voucher as $vouchers)
  if($from==$vouchers){continue;}
  echo $from.'<br/>';
   }
  ```

Thanks in advance Derrick

Comment: please please please. format your code....

Comment: Keep in mind that php mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Use php Mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PHP PDO (http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html). The reason for it to be deprecated are the many security holes that exist in php mysql, so if you plan to use this code on a live site (production environment) you could face SQL injection attacks and other scary things.

Comment: Am a beginner when it comes to php so thank for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your continue only continued the inner **foreach**.
To also continue the outer **for**, use

```
continue 2;
```

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Best regards

Zsolt